# SafeCracker and Querying the database in the search for duplicate content

Tags: safecracker, ajax, jquery

I have a safecracker form which I am using to register contacts for a contact manager. In an effort to eliminate duplications I would like the safecracker form to query the database and check for duplicate email or names in the contact entries.

I tried to install Ajax form Validator Plugin but the plugin does not seem to work and the developer is not responding in the help section.

How can I use Jquery/Ajax to perform an inline check before submitting the form?

Below is the script for the faulty Ajax Form Validator:

```
{exp:ajax_form_validator:script entry_id="none" form_id="comment_form" submit_button_id="submit_button" async_url="http://www.elinex.co.za/contact-manager/ajax_form_validator_async/" parse="inward"}

{ajax_form_validator field="name" required="yes" deny_duplicate_data_field="exp_members.screen_name|exp_members.username" duplicate_data_exception_field="exp_members.email" duplicate_data_exception_contained_in="email" field_required_alert_text="ERROR!\nName field cannot be empty!" invalid_indicator_id="name_field" invalid_class="invalidated" javascript_alert="yes" min_length="2" max_length="30" regex="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.\_\-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/" min_length_alert_text="ERROR!\nThe name cannot consist of one letter." max_length_alert_text="ERROR!\nThe name cannot be longer than 30 characters." duplicate_data_alert_text="ERROR!\nThe name you entered is already in use by a registered member." regex_alert_text="ERROR!\nThe name you entered contains illegal characters or character combinations."}

{ajax_form_validator field="email" required="yes" deny_duplicate_data_field="exp_members.email" duplicate_data_exception_field="exp_members.screen_name|exp_members.username" duplicate_data_exception_contained_in="name" field_required_alert_text="ERROR!\nEmail field cannot be empty!" invalid_indicator_id="email_field" invalid_class="invalidated" javascript_alert="yes" max_length="50" max_length_alert_text="ERROR!\nThe email address cannot be longer than 50 characters." regex_alert_text="ERROR!\nInvalid email address." duplicate_data_alert_text="ERROR!\nThe email you entered is already in use by a registered member." regex="/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]:LD:2,6:RD:$/i"}

{/exp:ajax_form_validator:script}

{exp:safecracker channel="member_profiles" url_title="{segment_3}" dynamic_title="[member_first_name] [member_last_name]" return="contact-manager/added/ENTRY_ID"}

<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="" class="text"/>

<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" class="text"/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" style="margin-left:0px;" value="Add Contact"/>

{/exp:safecracker}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, ignoring the AJAX Form Validator, which I'm unfamiliar with.

> How can I use Jquery/Ajax to perform an inline check before submitting the form?

You can create a template that loads a segment variable, such as the email address, into an `exp:query` tag/SQL statement, and check for the address that way. You can then return a 1 or a 0.

If the URL is /email-check/someone@somewhere.com

```
{exp:query sql="Select * from exp_channel_data where field_id 2 = '{segment_2}'}
{if total_results > 0}1{if:else}0{/if}
{/exp:query}
```

Now you can just use your own jQuery/AJAX code to pass the email address to that template's URL, and validate the form based on the 1/0 response.

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to implement the email check url but a cannot get a reponse (1/0) when using your suggested code for the sql query. Just shows a blank page.

Comment: `{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_channel_data WHERE field_id_24 = {segment_3}}
{if total_results > 0}1{if:else}0{/if}
{/exp:query}`

Comment: If segment_3 is not an integer, you need to wrap it in single quotes so MySQL compares a string. Check that first? Have you enabled the Query module under your Add-ons?

Comment: Thanks again for your assistance on this. I got it to work correctly by returning either a 1 or 0. Only problem I am having difficulty with is Remote JQuery Validation, I am not sure how to send the input data to the URL and receive a response. Currently the form does not submit and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: `$("#form").validate({
rules: {
member_first_name: {
required: true},
member_email_address: {
required: true,
email: true,
remote:'http://localhost/elinex/index.php/contact-manager/email-check/' + $('#member_email_address').val()
}
}
});`

Comment: I'm really not sure how the `validate()` function you're using works there. You'll need to look up what the `remote` param supports for a response. I'm assuming your validator plugin lets you write custom validation functions. In that case, you could do an `emailCheck` function that would just have a <a href="http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/">jQuery AJAX</a> call within it. You could translate your `1` & `0` into something that function passes to the validator that matches its criteria for success/fail.